# Send files as post request to next API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, http, next.js

How can I send a media file (form data) to an API (nextjs). So I can perform some work on it (nodejs).

*Frontend*

onClick => `query("/api/upload/", image)`
Where image is the file to upload.

*API*

```
Async function handler(req, Res){
    ...
    Const buff = Buffer.from(req.body);
    Somefunc(buff); // perform some tasks
    ...
}
```

But after carrying out the operation on `buff`, I found out that `req.body` was of type `string` and `buff` was useless because it contained `binary data`.

How can I receive the media file in the correct representation in the API so I can carry out `somefunc` on it??

Using the `fs.readfilesync` module produced the image file as it is after reading it from the system (local files).

But such was not the case for files transferred over http.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `multipart/form-data` so binary files are not encoded.

There are many ways to post including natively but if you used something like the  `axios` library, you could do something like

```
 axios
      .post("/api/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: I know how to post to the API, what am asking is. Recieving the image as an image representation not as a binary data from the API.

Comment: After the image is sent via post request, console logging it returns jibberish instead of proper image data. `query()` already abstracts this away for me.

Comment: how exactlly are you sending it `res.send` ? post that code,